# PHP - Calculate the difference between two dates

Tags: php, sql

I want to calculate the number of years between two dates.  One of them is retrieved from the database while the other is taken from user input in date format.

I used this code to get the date from the user:

```
$today   = $_POST['to-day'];
$tomonth = $_POST['to-month'];
$toyaer  = $_POST['to-year'];
$dateto  = date("$toyaer-$tomonth-$today");
```

And here is how I calculated it with the one retrieved from the database,

```
$start      = $leaveresult['date']; // i took from database 
$end        = strtotime($dateto);   
$difference = abs($end - $start);
$years      = floor($difference / (60*60*24*365));
```

The problem is that the result I get is always `0`.

I tried different methods but all of them resulted with `0` and one of them resulted with a huge number.

Comment: Is there a reason `$toyaer` is spelled that way?

Comment: Hint: You're subtracting strings.

Comment: $today,$tomonth and $toyAEr are assigned the same value in your actual code too?

Comment: Jeremy Holovacs : no .. it just a varible ..

Comment: Damien Pirsy  : thank u I copy it wrongly :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested but I think something like this will work:

```
$today = $_POST['to-day'];
$tomonth = $_POST['to-month'];
$toyear = $_POST['to-year'];
$dateto = "$toyear-$tomonth-$today";

$start = $leaveresult['date'];// i took from database 
$end = strtotime($dateto);   
$difference = abs($end - $start);
$years = floor($difference / (60*60*24*365));
```

I am assuming `$leaveresult['date']` is unix timestamp

Also please note that I fixed the post variable names.

If the start date is not in unix timestamp then use

```
$start = strtotime($leaveresult['date']);// i took from database
```

Comment: it still does not work .. whatever date i test the result is 4 concated with the forth digit of the year .. let say the start date :"2012-07-16" and the end date : "2016-07-16" the result is 46

Comment: @proR As I said I was assuming the `$leaveresult['date']` is in unix timestamp but seems like its not. so try `strtotime($leaveresult['date'])`

Answer (score 2):

The [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class simplifies all this by giving you a [diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method. This will return a [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object which you can get the values you're looking for.

Assuming `$_POST` looks like this:

```
$_POST = array(
    'to-year' => 2010,
    'to-month' => 8,
    'to-day' => 22
);
```

And `$leaveresult['date']` looks like this:

```
$leaveresult = array(
    'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 years')));
```

You can do something like this...

```
$input_date = new DateTime(sprintf("%d-%d-%d", $_POST['to-year'], $_POST['to-month'], $_POST['to-day']));
$database_date = new DateTime($leaveresult['date']);

$diff = $database_date->diff($input_date);

echo $diff->format('%r%y years') . PHP_EOL;
echo $diff->format('%r%m months') . PHP_EOL;
echo $diff->format('%r%d days') . PHP_EOL;

$years = $diff->y;
```

Which will yield

```
3 years
1 months
5 days
```

And `$years` will equal `3`

Answer (score 1):

you need in both cases a timestamp - the one you formatted ( as date object ) and the one you get from the database...
so I think you'r approach wasn't wrong, if your getting timestamps in both cases... but finally you've tried to round the number with floor... and of course this will result in 0, if it's less than a year.
test it without rounding first, and test your timestamps, maybe something is wrong there, too?